# Devel and XHProf configuration!

Tags: 6, performance, debugging

I have installed [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) and [XHprof](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/) to [profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiling_%28computer_programming%29) (kind of performance analysis) my website . Configured everything but i am confused with this setting

> **XHProf URL**: Path to the publically accessible xhprof_html - required to display profiler reports. You will need to set this up
>   outside Drupal, for example at http://xhprof.localhost/xhprof_html

my drupal installation is in inside /www/ 
please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set up a virtual host on your server and put the xhprof front-end HTML files on it (the ones that come with the the xhprof download). Give the host an address (e.g. http://xhprof.localhost/xhprof_html as suggested), then give that path to Devel.

Then you should get the link at the bottom of each page to check the profiling information for that request.

Comment: no need to create a subdomain? sorry i am not much familiar with virtual host thing.. thas why

Comment: No a subdomain isn't necessary, the files just need to be located at a host on the same machine